# Connect to Postgresql database in the local network

Tags: java, postgresql

I’m trying to connect to Postgresql database that is in the same network with my computer using Java application. 
When I was using localhost (or 127.0.0.1) all works fine, but when I replaced it with the local IP of my computer, the connection refused error occurred. 
I edited the pg_hba.conf file:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all            192.168.0.0/16       trust
host    all             all            127.0.0.1/24       trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
host  all  all  fe80::/10  trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             192.168.1.15/24          trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
host  duplicate  all  fe80::/10  trust
```

The listen_addresses in postgresql.conf:

```
#listen_addresses = ‘*’     # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

So I still can not connect to the DB.
When i removed this from pg_hba.conf

```
    local   all             all                                     trust
```

The connection refused error occurred event when I used localhost / 127.0.0.1 to connect. 
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

this is a comment

`#listen_addresses = ‘*’     # what IP address(es) to listen on;`

change it to

`listen_addresses = ‘*’     # what IP address(es) to listen on;`

restart the postgres server and everything else is fine.

Hope this helps !